# Custom message header file not generated

Tags: arduino, rosserial, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to send a custom message from a ros publisher to an arduino mega using  rosserial.The package containing the the publisher and custom message builds fine.I  tried to generate headers for the custom message by using the command `rosrun rosserial_client make_library.py path_to_libraries message_package` given in [rosserial_client/tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_client/Tutorials/Generating%20Message%20Header%20Files) but it failed to generate the required header file for arduino.Can someone help me?
The custom message file contains just two int16 variables.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238738/custom-message-header-file-not-generated/) by [renjith](https://answers.ros.org/users/27201/renjith/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on 2016-07-05**:
Did you remember to delete the old roslib folder in the libraries folder before running make_library.py?

**Comment by [renjith](https://answers.ros.org/users/27201/renjith/) on 2016-07-05**:
Yeah i tried that too but no result.

**Comment by [renjith](https://answers.ros.org/users/27201/renjith/) on 2016-07-06**:
Thanks Icehawk101.When i deleted the roslib and ran `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py ~/sketchbook/libraries` ,the required header files were generated.

**Comment by [vmatos](https://answers.ros.org/users/17756/vmatos/) on 2016-07-07**:
Please accept his answer, so the topic is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Always remember to delete the old roslib folder in the libraries folder before running make_libraries.py, otherwise the header files won't be generated for the Arduino

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-07-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2